# encrypting password in python script

Tags: python, encryption

I have a python script where i am using username and password to to perform operation(get/delete)on server using rest api.

I want to encrypt password used in script so that people who open the script won't be able to see plaintext password.

```
req = requests.delete(url, stream=True, headers=headers, verify=False,
                      auth=('Administrator','password'))
```

second problem is if i go for xor encryption for temporary purpose like below

```
passwd = base64.b64decode("cGFzc3dvcmQ=")

req = requests.delete(url, stream=True, headers=headers, verify=False,
                      auth=('Administrator',passwd))
```

passwd don't work inside `auth()` function as a variable.

Comment: You seem to use `'pass'` (a string) instead of the `pass` variable. Also please consider not naming a variable `pass` anyway, 'pass' is a python statement, use e.g. `password`.

Comment: Erm... why mustn't the user know the password?

Comment: @sphere: thanks , i actually used without single quote too, which is giving me syntax error in request.delete () line during script execution and used passwd variable (corrected it.)

Comment: @peter: script is kept on shared server and login user is common for all team members and don't want to expose  plain text password hard coded in script to other people for security reason.

Comment: Any way you store the password, whoever reads the script will see how you decrypt it and will be able to follow the same procedure. Store the password elsewhere or make the user type it in.

Comment: How will this script be used? If you run it manually, just use `getpass` and type it in.

Comment: @mad physicist, Blender :  I want to run the script in non interactive  user mode and don't want to provide password manually.  script will be called and executed  by other service after getting an alert.

Comment: My answer covers that option too.

Comment: If you put an encoded string into a file... and its decoded anywhere INside of the file, then its pretty easy to figure out what the encoded string is. If its decoded OUTside of the file, then the encoded string basically just became the password that anyone with additional know-how can do whatever they want.

Answer (score 6):

If your greatest risk is people who open your script, don't store the password in the script. No matter what algorithm you use to decrypt an encrypted password stored in the script, the unauthorized user will be able to figure it out and apply it just by opening the script.

You have a couple of options at this point

1. Store the password in a file with the appropriate permissions set, so that no one outside your group can open it. At this point you probably don't need to encrypt the password, since again, anyone reading your script would immediately know how to decrypt it.
2. Use the [`getpass.getpass`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/getpass.html#getpass.getpass) function to just have authorized users enter the password at a prompt. That way, you don't have to store it anywhere at all. This can not be used directly in a non-interactive script, but you can wrap your Python script in another script that pipes in the password. With the right permissions, this is roughly equivalent to option #1.

Comment: Thanks: i chose 1st approach to store password in file and encrypt it but i am still stuck with my second problem  passing passwd's value in rquest.delete url.  

requests.delete(url, stream=True, headers=headers, verify=False,
                      auth=('Administrator',passwd))
       
       
How can i pass the value of passwd inside the auth(). It takes passwd as a string only.
***working scenario is   requests.delete(url, stream=True, headers=headers, verify=False,
                      auth=('Administrator','actual_password'))